# Uploading file in asp.net without a post back

Tags: c#, file-upload

I'm trying to upload a file without a page refresh. I'm doing this with ASP.net and C#. I've found lots of examples of people having a form that targets an iframe and am trying to recreate it. But these examples are all in php so I'm flying blind somewhat. I've set this up but the I keep getting a Invalid View State error when submitting.

```
<div id="FileUploadDiv" class="hidden">
<form id="form2" action="FileUpload.aspx" enctype="multipart/form-data" runat="server" target="fileFrameP">
File: <input type="file" name="fileUpload" />
      <input type="hidden" id="FileReviewID" value="" />
      <input type="submit" name="fileSubmit" value="Submit" />
</form>
<iframe id="fileFrameP" name="fileFrameP" src="#" style="width:0; height:0; border:0px;"></iframe>
</div>
```

When I try this, I get this error:

```
Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that <machineKey> configuration specifies the same validationKey and validation algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that <machineKey> configuration specifies the same validationKey and validation algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster.

Source Error: 


[No relevant source lines]
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET MVC or web forms?

Comment: If you are using web forms then read [here](http://midnightprogrammer.net/post/Upload-Multiple-Files-With-jQuery-Uploadify.aspx) and if you are using MVC then read [here](http://midnightprogrammer.net/post/Upload-Files-In-RAZOR-With-jQuery-Uploadify-Plugin.aspx) and [here](http://midnightprogrammer.net/post/Upload-and-Show-Image-Without-Post-Back-With-Jquery.aspx)

Comment: I'm embarassed to say this but I'm not sure. How do you tell? I know I'm using aspx files, does that help? As you can see from the code, I'm trying to steer away from using the ASP controls. The main reason for that is I don't want to have to use the server click events. Perhaps I'm making this more complicated than it needs to be though by putting the file form in the main page and making the iframe the target. I suppose this would be easier if I put the file form in the iframe.

Answer (score 1):

You may use Ajax uploader or [SWFUpload](http://swfupload.org/).